# How to fix this view with constraints

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, swift2

Everyone. I am new in swift, so I don't know how to fix this view with constraints. I used 'Add Missing Constrains' and 'Reset To Suggested Constrains' to this view and added each element custom constrain but I don't fix this view. Please, advise me.

(I have used any of any view)

**my view:**

[image: view]

**and rotated view:**

[image: rotated view]

Comment: Thats a tough question to answer in this format. Using 'Add Missing constriants' and 'reset to Suggested constraints' will work only in very simplistic scenario.

I suggest you first define the rules for the placement of the various UI elements. Only then we can try and express these rules using constraints.

Comment: @TheAppMentor, thanks answer. I will try.  if you know some good tutorial, please, give me link.

Comment: Very tough to answer this. You should add constraints to each object in the UI instead of `Add Missing Constraints`, and `Suggested Constraints`. Check the answer below with the tutorials and get started from there. There are no shortcuts for auto layout. I learned the hard way!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that  'Add Missing constriants' and 'reset to Suggested constraints' work only in very specific cases.

This is a great tutorial for it - [Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) - [Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this view. I added uiview and bottom uilabels added to this uiview so view like this:

[image]

it worked perfect. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

All your views need x,y co-ordinates and size(width and height). So in your case the label should have leading and top constraints then intrinsic size as place holder. For the tick mark image right and top constraints are needed.